# Passing a Factory Class instance through Express Middleware

Tags: typescript, express, dependency-injection, middleware, factory

I'm working with a NodeJS/Express microservice and trying to get an instance of all my necessary class objects needed for a particular route.

I would like to be able to pass in dependencies to each of my middleware functions, but I can't find the best way to pass dependencies through my middleware chain.

My router currently looks like:

```
ModelRoute.post(
  '/',
  ModelController.factoryCreate(),
  ModelController.validateData(),
  ModelController.sendData(),
  ModelController.sendResponse(),
);
```

The factoryCreate is a controller function that creates an instance of the factory:

```
  factoryCreate() {
    return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      let factory = Container.get(AbstractFactory);
      res.locals.Class = factory.getClass();
      res.locals.Client = factory.getClient();
      res.locals.Response = factory.getResponse();
      return next();
    };
  }
```

As you can see, I'm passing the objects through res.locals, but hoping I could do it on a controller level?

And this is my factory class:

```
@Service('AbstractFactory')
export default class AbstractFactory {
  constructor(
    private _Client: extClient,
    private _Class: extClass,
    private _Response: extResponse,
  ) {}

  getClient(): extClient {
    return this._Client;
  }

  getClass(): extClass {
    return this._Class;
  }

  getResponse(): extResponse {
    return this._Response;
  }
}
```

Any way to better structure this code would be appreciated. I'm using typedi for DI.